# Example of homogeneous function which is not a product of radial and angular functions

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, polynomials

Is there any example of a homogeneous degree $k$ function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which cannot be written as $f(x)= R(r) \Omega (\omega)$ where $R$ is a radial function and $\Omega$ depends only on the coordinates on the unit sphere. Homogenous polynomials can be written like that, and they are dense in the space of continuous functions, does this imply that any continuous function can be written as a product as above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Homogeneity directly implies that

$$f(r \cdot \omega) = r^k \cdot f(\omega)$$

where $r \geqslant 0$ and $\omega$ is from the unit sphere.

Comment: What is the proof of this? oh I see $f(x/|x| |x|)$ and expand

Comment: Is the same result true for any continuous function?

Comment: @inquisitor No, this fails even for $f : \mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \} \to \mathbb{R},$ because if it were true, we would have $f(x) = R(x) \Omega(1)$ and $f(-x) = R(x) \Omega(-1)$ for $x > 0$, hence $f(x) f(-1) = f(-x) f(1)$ - it's easy to find a counterexample.